# how to read/use imported table from API into javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using an API from Caspio to import a Data Table that will be variable.

for that, I am doing the following

```
<script type="text/javascript" id='Test' src="https://c1afw487.caspio.com/dp/6e444000877ca58e63624b0b8c78/emb"></script>
```

and then to format it (send it to the bottom of my web page) I am doing this:

```
 <div id='InfoTable' style='width: 40%; float: left;'>
 <a id='TestTwo' href="https://c1afw487.caspio.com/dp/6e444000877ca58e63624b0b8c78">DataTable </a>
 </div>
```

Now, I am trying to access the data from the table. For that I am trying something like this

```
var DataTest = document.getElementById('Test');
var DataTestTwo = document.getElementById('TestTwo');


console.log(JSON.stringify(DataTest));
console.log(JSON.stringify(DataTestTwo));
```

But the first test returns { } and the second one null (notice how I tried to give an ID to the imported table so I could access it but any of my attempts worked).

What is the proper way to access the Table?

Comment: You can't get the json from an a anchor element. You will need to call the page by the href u mention, maybe thru ajax if that is your aim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know anything about that specific API but quick google seems to suggest that they have a separate rest api for requesting JSON data. You should look into that.

Stringifying an html element does nothing usefull...its an html element not your request payload data.

You can go over the table itself and extract all the contents into a json.
Something like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/wvdoek03/14/

```
var getHeaders = (table) => {
    const headerRow = table.tBodies[0].children[0];
    const headers = [];
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < headerRow.children.length; i++) {
        headers.push(headerRow.children[i].innerText);
    }
    return headers;
}
var getData = (table) => {
    const data = [];
    let i;
    for (i = 1; i < table.tBodies[0].children.length; i++) {
        let newDataRow = [];
        for (j = 0; j < table.tBodies[0].children[i].children.length; j++) {
            newDataRow.push(table.tBodies[0].children[i].children[j].innerText);
        }
        data.push(newDataRow);
    }

    return data;
}



JsonTable = function() {
  const table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    const headers = getHeaders(table);
  const data = getData(table);
    this.getRow = (rowNr) => {
    const result = {};
    headers.forEach((key, index) => {
            result[key] = data[rowNr][index];
    });
        return result;
  }

  console.log('table', table, 'has data:', data, ' and headers ', headers);
}
const jsonTable = new JsonTable();
console.log('First row is', jsonTable.getRow(0));
console.log('Second row is', jsonTable.getRow(1));
```

You can view the console output on jsFiddle to see what it looks like.
( use inspect developer tool to see console output )

[image]

Comment: One question, when I run the link you sent me, in the console only appears the API table, but not the console.log you were trying to show with this "console.log('First row is', jsonTable.getRow(0));" or am I wrong?

Comment: @RodrigoZazuetaDonnadieu added an example image - use dev console

Comment: Hello again, I have been stuck for a long time, I can see your jsfiddle.net code works exactly the way I need, but when I try to replicate the same on the code playground I use (I am totally new as you can see) I receive this message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tBodies' of undefined.

Please look at this link for further details: https://code.sololearn.com/Wp486738Qvsk

Comment: @RodrigoZazuetaDonnadieu Its probably because the playground runs the script before the page was ready. Adding a timeout or using an onload event would fix that. e.g: https://code.sololearn.com/WP4f9uXnDJX3/#html